# addListenerOnButton is not working in fragments in andriod studio

Tags: java, android, tabs, onclicklistener, buttonclick

This is the fragment code and I've tried various ways here to implement button listener, but none of them are working.  I've tried addListenerOnbutton, OnClick method and also tried to use this code in mainactivity. But none of them actually worked.Any suggestion could help me a lot.

```
   public class tab2 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10,b11,b12,b13,b14,b15,b16,b17,b18,b19;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        addListenerOnButton();

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
    }

    void addListenerOnButton(){

        /*b1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      System.out.println("Error has occurred");
                                  }
                              });*/
       /* b1 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b3 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b3);
        b4 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b4);
        b5 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b5);
        b6 = getView().findViewById(R.id.b6);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);*/
    }


    public void Activity1()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Activity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

   ....... until Activity19().....
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        /*switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.b1:
                Activity1();
                break;
            case R.id.b3:
                Activity3();
                break;
            case R.id.b4:
                Activity4();
                break;
            case R.id.b5:
                Activity5();
                break;
            case R.id.b6:
                Activity6();
                break;
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: All of your code in that method is commented out.  What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button b1, b2;

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = view.findViewById(R.id.b2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}

private void callActivity(Class activity) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), activity));
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.b1:
            callActivity(FirstActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.b2:
            callActivity(SecondActivity.class);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u sir, the app is opening but when i click on the button, the app is force stopped. Still its not properly functioning. Should i make any other changes??

Comment: can you share your logcat please, let see why is crashing

Comment: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.navigation.tabs/com.navigation.tabs.Activity1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Thank u sir, I got the output